# Checkbox to field values in SAS

Tags: sas

I have several variables that have checkbox values.
If the variables have "yes" values, I want a new field that shows the variable names in a list.
For example, the variable names are apple, banana, orange
The values for each variable: apple = yes, banana = no, orange = yes
So, the new variable would display: apple;orange

Comment: Some examples of what you have and what you need would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this seems like what you're asking for.

```
data want;
set have;
array vars apple banana orange;
do _t = 1 to dim(Vars);
if vars[_t]='yes' then varlist = catx(';',varlist,vname(vars[_t]));
end;
run;
```

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your help. I think this is really close to what I'm looking for, but I'm getting the error "Mixing of implicit and explicit array subscripting is not allowed." Do you know how I can get around this? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

So, something along these lines?

```
DATA Work.YesVariables;
    SET Work.AllVariables;

    WHERE Value = 'yes';

    KEEP Name;
RUN;
```

The WHERE clause does the filtering and the KEEP clause narrows the columns down to just the name.